# Async await doesn't work with dynamic parameter

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have a problem passing `dynamic` parameter to the async method. Compile time error says `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'`.

Actually, I am trying to log entries for each DB table column entries. So, I am using a generic method which takes dynamic `oldervalue` and `newvalue` and perform insertion into the AuditDB.

**Code**

```
    public async Task Translog(int Id, string Action, DateTime RecordTimeStamp, dynamic oldervalue, dynamic newvalue, VIBRANT db, VibrantAuditEntities context)
    {
        try
        {
            #region FrameLog
            Type typeOfMyObject;
            if (oldervalue != null)
                typeOfMyObject = oldervalue.GetType();
            else
                typeOfMyObject = newvalue.GetType();

            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeOfMyObject.GetProperties();

            var tasks = properties.ToList().Select(i => SetPropValuess(typeOfMyObject, i, Id, Action, RecordTimeStamp, oldervalue, newvalue, db, context));
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // Compile error at this line

            #endregion
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public async Task SetPropValuess(Type typeOfMyObject, PropertyInfo item, int Id, string Action, DateTime RecordTimeStamp, dynamic oldervalue, dynamic newvalue, VIBRANT db, VibrantAuditEntities context)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            string PropertyTypeNamespace = typeOfMyObject.GetProperty(item.Name).PropertyType.Namespace;
            if (PropertyTypeNamespace != "System.Collections.Generic" && PropertyTypeNamespace != "ClassLibrary")
            {
                if (oldervalue != null && newvalue != null)
                {
                    //Edit
                    bool chk = Comparer.Equals(oldervalue.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(oldervalue, null), newvalue.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(newvalue, null));
                    if (chk == false)
                    {
                        //  make and add log record
                        AuditLog al = new AuditLog();
                        al.TableName = (typeOfMyObject.BaseType.Name == "Object" ? typeOfMyObject.Name : typeOfMyObject.BaseType.Name);
                        al.EventDateUTC = RecordTimeStamp;
                        al.OriginalValue = Convert.ToString(oldervalue.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(oldervalue, null));
                        al.NewValue = Convert.ToString(newvalue.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(newvalue, null));
                        al.ColumnName = item.Name;
                        context.AuditLogs.Add(al);
                    }
                }
                else if (oldervalue != null && newvalue == null)
                {
                    //Delete
                    AuditLog al = new AuditLog();
                    al.TableName = (typeOfMyObject.BaseType.Name == "Object" ? typeOfMyObject.Name : typeOfMyObject.BaseType.Name);
                    al.EventDateUTC = RecordTimeStamp;
                    al.OriginalValue = Convert.ToString(typeOfMyObject.GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(oldervalue, null));
                    al.NewValue = null;
                    al.ColumnName = item.Name;
                    al.EventType = Action;
                    context.AuditLogs.Add(al);
                }
                else if (oldervalue == null && newvalue != null)
                {
                    //Create
                    AuditLog al = new AuditLog();
                    al.TableName = (typeOfMyObject.BaseType.Name == "Object" ? typeOfMyObject.Name : typeOfMyObject.BaseType.Name);
                    al.EventDateUTC = RecordTimeStamp;
                    al.OriginalValue = null;
                    al.NewValue = Convert.ToString(typeOfMyObject.GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(newvalue, null));
                    al.ColumnName = item.Name;
                    context.AuditLogs.Add(al);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange, for some reason the fact that there is a parameter of type 'dynamic' affects the type of Tasks. If the dynamic parameters are removed then it works. As a workaround you can add a cast, but would be interesting to understand why this happens:.

```
            var tasks = properties
                .ToList()
                .Select(i => SetPropValuess(typeOfMyObject, i, Id, Action, RecordTimeStamp, oldervalue, newvalue, db, context))
                .Cast<Task>();
```